# Summing data in excel from offset cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

***Dataset:***
[image]

***Results:***
[image]

Essentially what I am trying to do is come up with a formula that takes the occurrence of a name and sums the total "winnings" associated with that name. Input dataset and ideal output in attached images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--($B$2:$I$3=B6)*($C$2:$J$3),0))
```

In case of older version you may need array entry means confirm formula with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

For google-sheet try-

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(--($B$2:$I$3=B6)*($C$2:$J$3),0)))
```

[image]